# codeigniter - How to get embed data in my case

Tags: codeigniter

i load data in my controller like

```
$name['name'] = "some text!";
$data['header'] = $this->load->view('header_view', $name, TRUE);
$this->load->view('myView', $data);
```

and in my view file: myView.php

```
echo $header;
```

how can i get data in $name ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$data['name'] = "some text!";
$data['header'] = $this->load->view('header_view', $data['name'], TRUE);
$this->load->view('myView', $data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't because when it comes to myView, the header view is allready processed and so data is allready incoroporated into the output string.

The only way is to copy (merge) the contents of $name into $data.

You can get embed data by parsing the content of $data['header'] but it is a really bad solution.

To solve this issue you can generate header and footer along the content inside your controller like that:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('content');
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Or you can use a template engine to include header/footer automaticly with the content template.
Infortunately, there is no buildin way to add an header easily in codeigniter. You'll have to come up with your own functions to do that in a helper or library (but you'll not be able to share data between header and content).